# Error runing a batch file from python spyder

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file from python spyder (in Anaconda). I use the next script:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("example.bat", cwd=r"C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\opening_files")

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

The bat file runs an analysis in Abaqus (finite element software). I can run the batch file from Abaqus with its python console, or from the console in python, but in Spyder(Python 3.4) I get these errors:

> -This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>
> Please contact the application's support team for more information.
> -SMAPython not responding

Comment: A batch file is not a true program - it is a script which runs through the console which may be causing problems. Try running the batch file through the console: `cmd /C example.bat`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I use the .bat to open a program. With python I have already the problem that I explained, but I have tried with Matlab (I can run the .bat file and open the program) and with cmd (I can run the .bat and open the program too). So why I have the error with python? Thanks